# How to disable Spring boots default error handling?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I already tried disabling the Default Error handling of Spring boot w/c throws

> {
>       "timestamp": 1575346220347,
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "exception": "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException",
>       "message": "401 Unauthorized",
>       "path": "/auth/login" }

By adding the ff. Config.

```
   @SpringBootApplication(exclude = ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
```

and

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

But I'm getting a bunch of HTML formatted Response instead of the JSON response it should be getting from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use Controller Advice to make a global exception handler. Inside the ControllerAdvice class, you can use @ExceptionHandler annotation to handle exceptions. Here is a good article about ControllerAdvice. https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f

Comment: I didnt knew the context of this a few months ago, now that I am doing a new API and MS from scratch, I just realized I need this annotation on my new project too, and had to source class configuration files with this annotation and my API now is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to disable SpringBoots automatic handling of Error responses however I was able to get the proper JSON Error Response  by wrapping my Rest Template request in a try catch and using a library in the rest template as it turns out there is a bug in Rest Template that wouldn't allow me to retrieve the Response body.

From

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

To

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Try-Catch Wrapping

```
 ResponseEntity resp = null;

try{
            resp = restTemplate.postForEntity(hostUrl+loginUrl, request,Object.class);
        }catch(HttpClientErrorException e)  {
            ErrorDto result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), ErrorDto.class);                
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, e.getStatusCode());
        }
```

ErrorDto.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ErrorDto {

    @JsonProperty("Message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("Reason")
    private String reason;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }
}
```